# Combo box in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, combobox

What is the simplest way to use a combo box in a NextJS web app?

Though the question looks basic, I have looked on the net but did not find any simple and working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [the MUI's Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) component.

"The autocomplete is a normal text input enhanced by a panel of suggested options.
The widget is useful for setting the value of a single-line textbox in one of two types of scenarios:

1. The value for the textbox must be chosen from a predefined set of allowed values, for example a location field must contain a valid location name: combo box.
2. The textbox may contain any arbitrary value, but it is advantageous to suggest possible values to the user, for example a search field may suggest similar or previous searches to save the user time: free solo."